# Getting an error when calling the Alamofire in a class function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire for fetching the data.URLRequestConvertible protocol is using for constructing the request.When calling the URLRequestConvertible enum in requested class function through Alamofire I'm getting an error like (Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(AFDataResponse) throws -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Any, AFError>) throws -> ()') to non-throwing function type '(AFDataResponse) -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Any, AFError>) -> ()')).In requested function where i'm fetching the result how i can used the generic?
Q1: Getting an error when fetching the  result
Q2: How i can used the generic in a function

URLRequestConvertible enum:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible{
    case getAllDishes
    var bseUrl : URL{
        return URL(string: "https://yummie.glitch.me/")!
    }
    var method: HTTPMethod{
        switch self {
        default:
            return .get
        }
    }
    var path:String{
        switch self{
        case .getAllDishes:
            return "dish-categories"
        }
    }
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = bseUrl.appendingPathComponent(path)
        var request =  URLRequest(url: url)
        request.method = method
        return request
    }
}
```

Calling requested func:

```
class NetworkLayer{
    class func requested(_ request:Router,completion:@escaping(Result<Data,Error>) -> Void){
        ProgressHUD.show() //if response comes that loader run
        AF.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in
            switch response.result{
                case .success(let data):
                    do{
                        let getDishesData = data as? [String:Any]
                        let resp = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: getDishesData?["data"], options: .prettyPrinted)
                        completion(.success(response))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error))
            }
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: There is a `do` but no `catch`? That's why it's failing. It's guessing that the block can `throw` an error.

Comment: `responseJSON` has already serialized the response `Data` for you, no need to do it yourself. Just access the serialized object or use `responseDecodable` for a real response type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Do-Catch Statement

**catch** – If the throwing method fails and raises an error, the execution will fall into this catch block.

```
class NetworkLayer{
    class func requested(_ request:Router,completion:@escaping(Result<Data,Error>) -> Void){
        ProgressHUD.show() //if response comes that loader run
        AF.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let data):
                do{
                    let getDishesData = data as? [String:Any]
                    let resp = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: getDishesData?["data"], options: .prettyPrinted)
                    completion(.success(response))
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more suggestion for you here no need to do JSONSerialization because responseJSON gives you direct response(That Alamofire will do JSONSerialization).

**Final code**

```
class NetworkLayer{
    class func requested(_ request:Router,completion:@escaping(Result<Data,Error>) -> Void){
        ProgressHUD.show() //if response comes that loader run
        AF.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let response):
                do{
                    print(response)
                    completion(.success(response))
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)`: Don't do that. Don't use the `localizedDescription`, do `print(error)`. Also, you might want to call `completion()` too... Maybe `completion(.failure(error))`.

Comment: Yes, true updated! Thanks.

Comment: Hello Abdul, let me know if you have any questions and if it works then please accept this answer so it will helpful for others too.

Comment: @Yogesh Patel You're right.